# Oracle Analytics Cloud - Unable to create Shared Folders

Tags: oracle-analytics-cloud

In Oracle Analytics Cloud, role BI Service Administrator can't create Shared Folder. In addition, I can't setting privileges in settings.

I created a folder in personal area and try to past it in shared folder, but obtain error OBI-01403 - Access denied to this path.In the classic home I can't see privileges of shared folders. BI Service Administrator have all the other roles.